# "Ambiguous reference to member 'init(...)" calling baseclass initializer

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, swift2, super

I have a baseclass:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?)
    {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { }
}
```

a subclass:

```
class OneViewController: ViewController
{
    private var one: One
    init(one: One)
    {
        self.one = one

        super.init(nibName: "OneNib")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { }
}
```

and a subclass of the above subclass:

```
class TwoViewController: OneViewController
{
    private var two: Two
    init(two: Two)
    {
        self.two = two

        super.init(nibName: "TwoNib") <== ERROR
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { }
}
```

At the indicated line I get the error:

`Ambiguous reference to member 'init(one:)'`

I don't understand why the compiler can't figure out I'm referring to `ViewController`'s `init()`, like it managed to do in `One`'s `init()`.

What am I missing and/or doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't understand why the compiler can't figure out I'm referring to ViewController's `init()`, like it managed to do in One's `init()`

It is because, from inside TwoViewController, the compiler can't *see* ViewController's `init`. The rule is:

**As soon as you implement a designated initializer, you *block inheritance* of initializers.**

Therefore, OneViewController has only *one* initializer, namely `init(one:)`. Therefore, that is the only `super` initializer that TwoViewController can call.

If you want ViewController's `init(nibName:)` to be present in OneViewController, you must *implement* it in OneViewController (even if all it does is to call `super`).

Comment: Thank you! Additionally `one` needs to be optional to prevent another: "Property 'self.one' not initialized at super.init call" error.

Comment: Or you could initialize `one` from the get-go, e.g. `var one = One()`. But note that your overall design here suffers from not quite making sense in this regard, because, by trying to skip a level in your ViewControllerTwo initializer, you're trying to bypass the requirement that all properties be initialized all the way up the hierarchy. The goal of my answer is not to encourage you to do what you're doing, but to answer the question you asked, namely, why the compiler was stopping you from doing it. :)

Comment: Can you show how to fix this please? I don't understand what I need to implement in my subclassed viewcontroller.

Comment: @PetrusTheron Where is your question?

Answer (score 3):

The chapter in the Swift manual on [Designated Initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203) will clarify it, but basically `OneViewController` has only one way to set `self.one`, and that's by initialising using `init(one: One)`. You cannot bypass that, which is what you are trying to do.

- If what you were trying to do *could* succeed, what value would `two.one` have in the following?

  ```
  let two = Two(two: SomeTwo)
  print(two.one)
  ```
- Answer - undefined. That's why it isn't allowed.

Having declared `One.init(one:)` it is now the Designated Initializer, and there's no way to go round it.

Comment: Would making `one` optional help?

Comment: I would have thought so, either that or setting it explicitly in `Two.init` (if you relax `private`), but actually, testing it in Playground shows that doesn't work... I guess that you have made `One.init(one:)` the Designated Initializer and there's no going back from that.

Comment: ... @Matt's answer is the right answer, as it explains why making it optional wouldn't work...

Comment: I tried and indeed error stays the same. Does this (and amazing @matt's answer) make your answer incorrect?

Comment: No, my answer is "correct" and explains logically why the original question couldn't work. @Matt's answer *also* explains why the get-round that both you and I thought might work wouldn't!

Comment: Thank you! I gave you 20 extra points (by upping two random great other answers of yours).

Answer (score 1):

you don't necessary pass value into constructor's ViewController . you can define public object in oneViewController and you access of outer .

```
 class OneViewController: ViewController {
    public var one: One

 }


let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OneViewController") as OneViewController

let one = One()
vc.one = one
```

Comment: Indeed, I've been thinking about this. But in the real code, where things are more complicated and there are more parameters, this would become rather ugly.